# Why are we only concerned with the exponent when differentiating to find the Maximum a posteriori probability?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Apologies in advance because this is a really simple calculus question, but I failed to find any answer and have really only basic level of calculus education.

In Wikipedia's [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_a_posteriori_estimation#Example) on Maximum a posteriori probability, it mentions that to find the $\mu$ that maximizes $P_{\mu|X}(\mu|x)$ we just need to minimize the exponent that has the negative signs ignored (presumably differentiating the function circled in red w.r.t. $\mu$, equates it to 0 and solve for $\mu$).

**I don't understand why we can only focus on differentiating the exponent (instead of the whole thing) while ignoring the negative signs? Wouldn't the constants also affect the maximum of the function? I also don't understand why the signs are ignored.**

Let me give a (certainly wrong) analogy. Suppose we wanna find the max/min of the function $y=a.b^x$; surely there is a difference between differentiating $a.b^x$ (the whole thing) and $x$ only (focusing on the exponent)?

Because the differential of the former is $ab^x ln(b)$ whereas for the latter it's $1$. Yet as far as I can see, this is very similar if you substitute $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_m}$ and $b=exp$. (Again, I am 100% sure I am wrong, but I can't see why, please help!)

[image]

Comment: They are ignoring the $\exp$ because it is increasing. And they are not really ignoring the minus sign: the maximization flipped into a minimization.

Comment: @athalhaids Sorry could you explain a bit more about the exp please?

Comment: They are focusing on the exponent as implicitly they are maximizing the logarithm of the expressions. Hence the usage log-likelihood.

Comment: @sku I replied to AI.G's answer below by going that direction, I think I almost got it, but I am still left with $\frac{1}{2}$ and the signs aren't right, could you see what I did wrong please?

Comment: @Constantlyconfused maximizing $-f(x)$ is same as minimizing $f(x)$. Second, the minimum values of $0.5 f(x)$ and $f(x)$ occur at the same value of $x$. So the half can be removed without loss of generality.

Comment: @sku Thank you very much, got it all cleared up now, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen in probability/stats classes the same "trick" to find extrema, it seems it's common across the field - to take the *logarithm* of your function.

First, the logarithm is *monotone*, i.e. it does not disturb extremas, and second, it simplifies products and exponents greatly - $\ln(\prod e^{x_i})=\sum x_i$.

It is equivalent to optimize $f$ and $\ln f$ precicely because $f(x)<f(y)$ implies $\ln f(x)<\ln f(y)$ (due to monotonicity of $\ln$), and conversely - $\ln f(x)<\ln f(y)$ implies $f(x)<f(y)$ (by exponentiation, which is monotone, too).

---

About the change of sign  and the disappearing factors.

When you take $\ln$ of the given expression, you arrive at an expression of the form $-\frac 1 2 E$. It will be *bigger* if $E$ is *smaller* (due to the minus sign). That is, $$\max\left(−\frac 1 2 E\right) = −\frac 1 2 \min E.$$ Note how now you only need to minimize $E$, and the wanted maximum is then $-\frac 1 2$ of it.

Comment: @AI.G. So what happened was we applied $ln$ to both sides:

$ln(f(\mu)f(x|\mu))=ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_m}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\mu-\mu_0}{\sigma_m})^2)\prod^n_{j=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_v}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma_v})^2))$

Comment: And RHS becomes:

$ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_m})+ln(exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\mu-\mu_0}{\sigma_m})^2))+\sum^n_{j=1}ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_v}exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma_v})^2))$

Comment: Simplifying it a bit:

$ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_m})-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\mu-\mu_0}{\sigma_m})^2+\sum^n_{j=1}(ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_v})-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma_v})^2)$

Comment: Then we do $\frac{dln(f(\mu)f(x|\mu))}{d\mu}$, but because $ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_m})$ and $ln(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_v})$ are constants so they disappear

Comment: But then we are still left with $-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\mu-\mu_0}{\sigma_m})^2-\sum^n_{j=1}(\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma_v})^2)$ - i.e. we still have $\frac{1}{2}$ and the signs aren't right - which isn't quite the same as the red circled?

Comment: @AI.G. Thank you very much, got it all cleared up now, appreciate it

Comment: Glad to help! :) I moved my comment into the answer so that we can clean up the comment section here.